# Regex to match binary numbers with more than two set bits

Tags: regex, binary

If I have a number consisting only of 1's and 0's and I need to create a regular expression that will match only if said number contains more than two instances of the digit 1.

Some examples:

```
1000000010001
0001100000000
1000110010000
0000001000000
0100010000000
```

I'd need my expression to correctly match the 1st and 3th examples.

I'm guessing this should be some basic stuff. The best I managed was:

```
1.+1.+(1)
```

It's giving me some problems though, so I'd like to know if there's a better way to go about this.

Comment: For starters, replace the `+`s with `*`s. What kind of problems are you having?

Comment: Do you want to capture the whole number that contains more than two instances of 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did was pretty good. I changed it up a little bit to match the complete number and accommodate all possible cases:

```
((?:0*1){3,}0*)
```

See an example [here](https://regex101.com/r/pW3hG7/1).

This is, of course assuming you only have binary numbers. If not, feel free to change up the `0` to `[02-9]` to include all other digits, too.

### Breakdown

`(?:0*1)` matched any number of `0` and then one `1`. `{3,}` means to find this group at least three times, this means there have to be at least three, i.e. more than two, `1`. Then we match any number of `0`s in case the number does not end in a `1` and to include the whole number in the match.

Comment: This one ended up working best for what I needed. Thanks for the reply and explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```
.*1.*1.*1.*
```

[**regex101 doodle**](https://regex101.com/r/aA7kQ2/1)

So three `1`'s with `.*` in between. The Kleene star means zero or more repetitions whereas the `.+` means *one* or more repetitions.

The first and last `.*` are not required if you don't use start (`^`) and end anchors `$`. Otherwise these are: `^.*1.*1.*1.*$`.

Or in case  - as @Kasra says - it is not guaranteed that the string contains only ones and zeros, you can use the regex:

```
10*10*1
```

To match the fragments or lines with `grep`. Or to match the full line:

```
^[0-1]*10*10*1[0-1]*$
```

Comment: Yeah seems that its so!

Comment: @raumaankidwai: that's not a problem. A regex matches as long as there is one path of states possible. So that's not problem. If you enter `01000111` it will indeed eat `1`s, but that will not make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
^0*10*10*1[10]*$
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
^(?:0*1){3}[10]*$
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cD2rD8/3)